# YouTube Video in R markdown

Tags: r, video, youtube, r-markdown

Is it possible to embed a YouTube video in a R Markdown?
So far what I have is

```
<a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=Q8rakpF7duU
" target="_blank"><img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/Q8rakpF7duU/0.jpg" 
alt="IMAGE ALT TEXT HERE" width="240" height="180" border="10" /></a>
```

but it only adds an image. Clicking on this image takes me to my browser where the video starts playing. Is there a way that allows me to play the video in the markdown document itself?

References:
https://github.com/adam-p/markdown-here/wiki/Markdown-Cheatsheet#videos

Comment: Does `iframe` work?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You will need to use iframe. For example adding a markdown video to the basic RMD template:

````
---
title: "iframe"
author: "Example"
date: "22 July 2016"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

## R Markdown

This is an R Markdown document. Markdown is a simple formatting syntax for authoring HTML, PDF, and MS Word documents. For more details on using R Markdown see <http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com>.

<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/6A5EpqqDOdk" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

When you click the **Knit** button a document will be generated that includes both content as well as the output of any embedded R code chunks within the document. You can embed an R code chunk like this:

```{r cars}
summary(cars)
```

## Including Plots

You can also embed plots, for example:

```{r pressure, echo=FALSE}
plot(pressure)
```

Note that the `echo = FALSE` parameter was added to the code chunk to prevent printing of the R code that generated the plot.
````

Note that the video will not appear in the preview window but will when viewed in a browser connected to the internet.

Answer (score 7):

The accepted solution did not work for me (2021) but this one did:

```
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/6A5EpqqDOdk" data-external= "1" > </iframe>
```

Comment: note the link is the `/embed/` version of the video, not the `watch?v=` version

Answer (score -6):

The answer may be as simple as this, I think:

```
![](https://youtu.be/zNzZ1PfUDNk)
```

Comment: This post is for providing url links, and doesn't answer the OP's question which is "how to embed" a link in Rmd