# How to embed local Video in R Markdown?

Tags: r, markdown, knitr, r-markdown, rnotebook

I already know [how to embed the youtube video in the R Markdown document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38517236/youtube-video-in-r-markdown).
But Suppose I have offline video, that I do not want to publish, in mp4 or avi format. Is there a way to embed it in the document? 
Something like the following (taking inspiration from image embedding):

```
![Caption](vid/video1.mp4)
```

Comment: I believe you have to use raw HTML syntax: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp

Comment: @Yihui I tried doing that, It shows the contained in the output file, but the video does not play. Do you think htat could be a problem with the chromium browser (Version 58.0.3029.81) on Ubuntu16.04

Comment: I tried myself and it seems a browser issue. In my mac, I can see the video in Safari, but not in Chrome.

Comment: Thanks @amatsuo_net, I tried opening the html in firefox, it showes the container, but gives error `No video with supported format  and MIME type found`. Probably, that is because I am using **.avi** file format. Any recomendation on what is the most compatible file format over browsers and operating systems?

Comment: html5 supports only mp4, webM and ogg. https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp At least it's necessary to convert the file to one of these formats (although I failed to view a file in mp4 in Chrome).

Answer (score 22):

This worked for me:

```
Slide With Code
========================================================
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

If you remove the width and height, and enable

```
autosize: true
```

R takes care of the size of the video.

Comment: I have the following code `## AI and Deep Learning
![](hadelin.mp4){width=400 height=300}
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="hadelin.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>`   But I get nothing, an outline of the video.  I have even left out the `![](hadelin.mp4){width=400 height=300}` and I still can't get it to render in a browser.

Comment: The above answer should work. The `video`  won't show up on the RStudio Viewer Pane so check using another browser, e.g. Google Chrome. See the `answer` here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53176203/how-to-embed-video-avi-mpg4-in-xaringan-slides

Answer (score 2):

Using [`iframe`](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_iframe.asp) worked for me

````
```{r}
video_path  <- "vid/"
video_files <- list.files(video_path,
                         pattern = "\\.mp4$",
                         recursive = TRUE,
                         all.files = FALSE,
                         full.names = TRUE)
```

<iframe width="720" height="480" src="`r video_files[1]`" align="middle" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
````

Comment: I couldn't disable autoplay using iframe (in bookdown).

Answer (score 0):

It also works to use an image tag

`<img src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>`

Answer (score -2):

See the code

```
![](https://www.yoursite.com/miniature.png)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xyz)
```

See the code