# how to embed video (avi/mpg4) in Xaringan slides

Tags: r-markdown, xaringan

I'm trying to embed some local videos into my xaringsn presentation.
I've succesfully embedded GIFs but I need more quality and AVI or MPG4 are mandatory

The issue is I can't get the video embedded no matter if I use markdown syntax or html syntax

```
![video](media/animation.avi)


<video width="320" height="240">
<source src="media/animation.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

any hint would be much appreciated

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your latter one with `video` should work. Just won't show up on the RStudio Viewer Pane so check using another browser, e.g. Google Chrome.