# How to play mp4 music file in my local folder on xaringan?

Tags: r-markdown, xaringan

I want to play mp.4 file on my xaringan slide, and I add the following but it won't play. Am I missing something here? Thank you.

```
<video width="500" height="400"  controls>
  <source src="music.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Comment: What do you mean by **it won't play?** You don't see the video on the slide or can't start it using video-controls? If the first case, see this https://stackoverflow.com/a/53181238/10858321

Comment: I did exactly the same way as the link you attached. The link shows up in the slide, but it does not play even when I click the arrow (play) button on the slide.

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem, In my case, this is working.

Comment: probably because of safari browser. thanks

Comment: If you have found your solution to the problem, please add that to your question, it might be helpful to others.

Comment: Not yet, but definitely I will do so once I found a solution. Thanks.

Comment: problem solved! It was due to the location of the file. thanks! just quick question: is there anyway I can play mp4 file with music only without showing video?

Comment: well just get the audio of that video and use that