# Embed a YouTube video in RMarkdown in 2021

Tags: r, r-markdown

All solutions found using Google don't work for me. Can someone show me a simplest possible `.Rmd` file that embeds a YouTube video?

According to [R Markdown: The Definitive Guide](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/learnr-videos.html) something as simple as `![](https://youtu.be/zNzZ1PfUDNk)` should work. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38517236/youtube-video-in-r-markdown) post on SO tells me to use:

```html
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://youtu.be/zNzZ1PfUDNk" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

My simple `.Rmd` file with only these two snippets looks like this:

```
![](https://youtu.be/zNzZ1PfUDNk)

<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://youtu.be/zNzZ1PfUDNk" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

But knitted to an HTML I only get this:
[image]

What am I missing here?

Comment: Looks like your output is not just a plane Rmarkdown file, have you tried the youtube video in an absolutely plain R markdown file?

Comment: Can you pastebin the file that works for you?

Answer (score 4):

I had the exact same problem, but found the answer. You have to install the package `"vembedr"` and then just write: `embed_url("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BD_n6ju9iRA")` in a codechunk. Works perfectly if you or anybody still need it.

You can also get more information here: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/vembedr/vignettes/embed.html